# How do I display business information using Google Maps API?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Previously, I would have gone to google, grabbed an iframe from the description of the organisation and simply pasted it into the page I was working on. The information box would show information about the business such as full address, phone number and website, etc. (see image below):

[image]

After deciding to redo my website from scratch I decided I would try to update the map as well. There were a couple of reasons for this. The new Google Maps looks more polished (personal preference) and using the API I could stylize the map to fit the color scheme of my site.

I started with a fairly simple bit of javascript:

```
function initialize(data) {

    var map;
    var someLoc = new google.maps.LatLng(####,#####);

    var MY_MAPTYPE_ID = 'custom_style';

    var featureOpts = [
    {
        "stylers": [
        { "hue": "#8800ff" },
        { "lightness": 33 }
        ]
    }
    ]

    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 12,
        center: someLoc,
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
            mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, MY_MAPTYPE_ID]
        },
        mapTypeId: MY_MAPTYPE_ID
    };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),mapOptions);

  var styledMapOptions = {
    name: 'Custom Style'
  };

  var customMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(featureOpts, styledMapOptions);

  map.mapTypes.set(MY_MAPTYPE_ID, customMapType);


}


$(document).ready(function(){
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
});
```

This gives me the following map:

[image]

However, I would like to display a marker for the business location and associated information so I add:

```
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: someLoc,
      map: map,
      title: 'Hello World!'
  });


}
```

But this means I get the organisation displayed on the map and the marker I have just created:

[image: Example]

Is it possible to get the same result as the iframe (first image) using the Google Maps API (V3)? Essentially I would like to get to show the associated information of the business when the page loads so I have something similar to:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found a fairly simple solution.

Set the maxZoom level so only the pin you create can be seen:

```
var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 12,
        maxZoom: 16,
        center: myLoc,
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
            mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, MY_MAPTYPE_ID]
        },
        mapTypeId: MY_MAPTYPE_ID
    };
```

Then add any other information using an [information window](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple).